# compile time assertion in c++

Tags: c++, generic-programming

I am reading a compile time assert, after searching online I got some code which I didn't understand.

```
template <bool> struct CompileAssert {};
#define COMPILE_ASSERT(expr, msg) \
    typedef CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
```

Used this COMPILE_ASSERT as below.

```
COMPILE_ASSERT(!sizeof(T*), PassRefPtr_should_never_be_assigned_to)
```

But I didnot got the Idea.Can someone help me In understanding the above piece of code.
Second got confused on this piece of code

```
typedef CompileAssert<(bool(expr))> msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]
```

The #define will replace  **COMPILE_ASSERT(expr, msg)** with above expession.but how **msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]** a alternative type for **CompileAssert<(bool(expr))>**.

Please someone explain in detail and simple manner. I have lot many many question.

Like why message(PassRefPtr_should_never_be_assigned_to) work without using "" for char *

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass an expression to the macro that evaluates to false, the macro will give a typedef like follows:

```
typedef CompileAssert<false> PassRefPtr_should_never_be_assigned_to[false ? 1 : -1];
```

which is

```
typedef CompileAssert<false> PassRefPtr_should_never_be_assigned_to[-1];
```

So, since negative array lengths are not allowed, the compiler will emit an error for the typedef, containing "msg" as the array name.

Comment: So Its doesnot matter weather complieAssert<true> or complileAssert<false> , It just check the validity of the arrayname is of corrrect name or not...

so I think It will be same if I use

typedef int  msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1]

Answer (score 1):

The `typedef` will name either a legal or illegal piece of code, based on the value of `expr`.

Let's say `bool(expr)` is `true`. In this case, the typedef is equivalent to

```
typedef CompileAssert<true> msg[1];
```

This is a 1-element array of `CompileAssert<true>` structures, named `msg`. Since `CompileAssert<bool>` is a defined structure, all is well.

However, if `bool(expr)` is `false`, the typedef will be equivalent to the following:

```
typedef CompileAssert<false> msg[-1];
```

This is of course illegal (you can't create an array of size -1), so the compiler will report an error that `msg` is ill-formed. And because `msg` is the macro parameter, it will actually be the text provided in `COMPILE_ASSERT`, so the error message for your example might look something like this:

```
Cannot create array PassRefPtr_should_never_be_assigned_to of size -1.
```

Also note that C++11 has a built-in `static_assert`.

Comment: `typedef CompileAssert<false> msg[-1];` you mean (changed true to false)

Comment: So Its doesnot matter weather complieAssert<true> or complileAssert<false> , It just check the validity of the arrayname is of corrrect name or not... so I think It will be same if I use typedef int msg[bool(expr) ? 1 : -1] –

Comment: @YSBhai Yes, it would work just as well with `int`. Normally, a bool-template is used when you only provide correct definition for the `true` case. This macro seems to be mixing these approaches without understanding them.